# How can I update the issue body of a github issue via the api?

Tags: github-api

I can't seem to find documentation regarding this. 
I want to update the body or title of an issue via the API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the documented solution. It is using the PATCH method. 
See here: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue

```
PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number
```

Request Parameters: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#parameters-3

Comment: This does not work with an simple access key. It only works with GitHub Apps. Its easier to use the GitHub CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You also have an alternative (which still uses the GitHub API): [GitHub CLI `gh` 1.6](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.6.0) (Feb. 2021)

> ### [GitHub CLI now supports editing issues and pull requests, and pull request auto-merge](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-18-github-cli-now-supports-editing-issues-and-pull-requests-and-pull-request-auto-merge/)

> GitHub CLI 1.6 now includes support for editing issues and pull requests, allowing you to:
>
> - Edit the title or body
> - Add metadata like labels, assignees, reviewers, projects, and milestones
>
> This latest release also supports enabling auto-merge for pull requests.
>
> [image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/108115726-625e3300-704f-11eb-9a26-b3c5b928253f.gif]

Comment: Using `gh` is a completely different issue that using the API directly.

Comment: @AndrewKS All that `gh` is doing is using the API directly. Set  `GH_DEBUG=api` and you will see those API calls. Except they are done for you.

Comment: @VonC The interesting thing is that PATCH /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/{issue_number} does only work with an GitHub App, not with an simple access key.  So the GitHub CLI is much easier to use for this task.