# Reporting GitHub issues using electron app

Tags: github, electron

From electron app menu, I would like to integrate GitHub issues. When a user clicks on "Report Issue" menu, a dialog opens and the user fills the form and clicks on "Submit", then the app adds the issue to the GitHub issues for the developer to debug the problem and release updates.

So how can one integrate GitHub issues with an app

Comment: Seems to be [possible](https://github.com/pksunkara/octonode#create-an-issue-for-a-repository-post-repospksunkarahubissues) with `octonode`. Could be more modules around as well.

Comment: See also GitHub API: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

Comment: Thank you all. I found curl to be useful for this. first create personal token on github and then use curl. more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235024/how-to-edit-a-github-issue-using-the-api-curl-especially-close. However, if one uses personal token, any one who has the token can post, and the posted issue will say " .. posted by you" instead of " ..posted by anonymous or something", which I needed anonymous or my app name and unique id or email of the user