# how to change/modify title of an issue when you learn more about the issue/underlying issue itself.

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I made a generic title while making a github issue. While trying to explain the issue, I discovered some more details underneath which I could add to the title to explain to the developer better.

I tried to change the title but wasn't able to do that, can modify the body of the message but not the title apparently :(

I tried using [github] modify title or modify heading and few other keywords but couldn't find anything in stackoverflow.com

I even re-read https://guides.github.com/features/issues/ just to see if I missed something when I had read it few years ago.

Looking to know.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2021: you can also use the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66267622/6309), instead of `curl`.

---

2018:
Considering the [GitHub API for Issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) does include an "[edit issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue)" which does allow for the title to be modified, this should be possible.

Try (using an [OAuth token](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/) as [shown here](https://gist.github.com/anzeljg/3898897#oauth)):

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <your OAuth token>' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -X PATCH \
     https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number \
--data '[{ "title": "a new title" }]'
```

Or:

```
curl --request PATCH -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" \
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number \
 --data '[{ "title": "a new title" }]'
```